# Cron jobs not running on Kubernetes + Alpine linux

Tags: cron, docker, alpine-linux, kubernetes

I am trying to run a cron job on Alpine Linux docker image which is then pushed in Kubernetes container. The Cron job is that I want the container to restart itself after every 15 mins. So my command is `pkill processname`.

Little bit about Alpine Cron jobs: For Alpine Linux cron is followed periodically that is it has already created folders /15min. /hourly. /daily. /weekly. /monthly. So I have to just copy my script in one of the folders to run it.

I created the script and as requested on Alpine FAQ's pages I didn't give any name extension to the file and copied it with execute permissions in the folder. When I try and run command `run-parts --test /etc/periodic/15min` it shows me that it has one script that needs to be executed. Although that script never executes. When I try and run that docker image on my local machine, not exactly with that script but a different one where I am just creating a file in the folder, it works well.

I have also tried and run `crond -f -l 8` on Kube cluster and ti still does not work.

I would really appreciate help on this part what I am missing or where is it going wrong.